# UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION - keeping process alive: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hey so I 'm trying to create a key bot for my website and it keeps giving me this error UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION - keeping process alive: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '
client ') and another one but reading type I'
m not sure what to do anymore here is the code that it keeps flagging

[code that it keeps flagging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP4Tm.png)

I've tried to delete stuff like before it was
[I've tried to delete stuff like before it was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHGLZ.png) 
and I still got the same error after removing stuff that may have caused it I'm not sure what to do anymore

```
let a = "`"
const tosend = new Discord.MessageEmbed(client)
.setColor('#0099ff')
.setTitle('Whitelist')
.setDescription(`Your Key Your Key Is ${a}${key}${a}`)
.setFooter("TIP: Always save your key, you cannot use until registered")
```

here is the error

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION - keeping process alive: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at MessageEmbed.setup (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\main\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:29:22)
    at new MessageEmbed (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\main\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:21:10)
    at module.exports.run (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\main\Bot\commands\whitelist.js:35:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\main\Bot\index.js:48:34)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\main\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\main\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\User\3D Objects\src\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\3D
```

Objects\srcmain\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)

I fixed it so the reason why It was broken was because as I was trying to update it messed up the discord.js I had installed plus I had to change the discord embed into RichEmbed thanks for the help though

Comment: Please add relevant code as text, not as images

Comment: I tried but it kept asking for me to format it right it wasn't working when did I fixed it

Comment: Thanks. Are you using discord.js v13? Is the code you pasted above from your `commands\whitelist.js` file?

Comment: Yeah I am but let me double check

Comment: Never mind I am not I am using 11.6.3 as my discord js

Comment: Ouch, that's pretty old, the latest is v14.7

Comment: And in v11 we had `RichEmbed`, `MessageEmbed` was used for received embeds only.

Comment: I was trying to update it but I messed up that's why there is message embed instead

Comment: Yes, you should really update, but the code will be a lot different so it's not easy. At the moment, you could replace `new Discord.MessageEmbed(client)` with `new Discord.RichEmbed()` and it should work. This part of your code at least :)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This is for Discord.js v14

I don't think you're constructing that embed correctly. The docs provide a good example:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor

```js
// at the top of your file
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });

channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
```

Comment: Hey so I tried what you recommended but now I have gotten another error.. the error is UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION - keeping process alive: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Comment: you need to say what error

Comment: that is the error

Comment: which line is it happening in?

Comment: I added it into the post sorry I miss read the first time (:

Comment: we don't know where `whitelist.js:35:17`, but my guess would be theres something wrong with how you're sending the embed

Comment: would it help if I just send all the code here?

Comment: put your current code in the post and let us know where the error is happening